# Getting error (gpg: can't open '–': No such file or directory)while adding docker GPG key

Tags: docker, ubuntu

While setup docker repository when I adding docker GPG key

cmd- curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add –

Getting error (gpg: can't open '–': No such file or directory)

[image: error]

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using an ascii code "-".

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -

This works, just be mindful of the "-" character at the end. Manually delete it and type it in your console if you have to as a test.